# How to Autofill and post next form based on form filled on previous Page

Tags: jquery, forms, wordpress

I have a wordpress form with a email field only, when someone fills the field and submit the forms he is redirected to other page with a thank you message.

That thankyou page again have a form with email field, what I need to do is to fill the second form automatically with the email filled in previous form.

Please let me know how I can do this thing using jquery.

Comment: How are you creating the forms, using a plugin? This will effect how you pre-populate the 2nd form.

Comment: Hi Andy,

I am creating the first form using a plugin "FormBuilder" from truthmedia and the second one is a newsletter subscription form from feedburner.

Answer (score 0):

You could just send the e-mail address (via a `GET` variable) to the "Thank You" page from the form processing script (where the user is being redirected from). Then can just do something like

```
$('#ID_OF_NEW_E-MAIL_FIELD').text("<?php echo $email_address_from_prev_page; ?>");
```

in the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Hello Tarek,

I am creating the first form using a plugin "FormBuilder" from truthmedia and the second one is a newsletter subscription form from feedburner. So I can't use the GET Variable because i need to post first form to database and email also..